# How to find the average value for consecutive zeros?

Tags: sql, t-sql, datetime, sql-server-2012

This is my table.

```
Site_name | date& Time              | PowerOutput         
----------+-------------------------+------------------
ACT0001   | 2013-07-21 01:00:00.000 | 196.852984494331  
ACT0001   | 2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 | 0   
xyz0001   | 2013-07-21 03:00:00.000 | 196.852984494331   
xyq0001   | 2013-07-21 04:00:00.000 | 196.958395639561 
xys0001   | 2013-07-21 05:00:00.000 | 0
xyd0001   | 2013-07-21 06:00:00.000 | 197.20098185022 
xye0001   | 2013-07-21 07:00:00.000 | 0 
xyg0001   | 2013-07-21 08:00:00.000 | 0     
cfg0001   | 2013-07-21 09:00:00.000 | 197.412144323522 
acb0001   | 2013-07-21 10:00:00.000 | 0 
bdf0001   | 2013-07-21 11:00:00.000 | 0 
olk0001   | 2013-07-21 12:00:00.000 | 196.886233049016
```

I am trying to update the values in places of zeros. If there is only one zero then I am able to update the table, but if there are consecutive zeros I am finding it difficult to update the table.

The logic is :

```
((Previous value-next value)/previous value)*100 <5
```

If this is true then it should insert the previous value

```
((Previous value-next value)/previous value)*100 >=5
```

If this is true then it should remain as zero.

This is the code I have so far:

```
;with cte as
(
    SELECT  
        *,
        lead(pr_output,1) OVER (ORDER BY (select null)) As PreviousValue,
        lag(pr_output,1) OVER (ORDER BY (select null)) As NextValue
    FROM
        [dbo].[My_table]
)
,ctee as
(
    select 
        *,
        abs((PreviousValue*100-NextValue*100)/(case when NextValue = 0 then 1 else NextValue end)) as CheckFlag
    from
        cte 
)
select
    Site_name,[DATE&Time],
    case 
        when pr_output <>0 then pr_output
        else
            case 
                when CheckFlag >= 5 then 0
                else PreviousValue
            end
    end as pr_output
from 
    ctee
```

I am unable to update the records in case of consecutive zeros.

Expected output:

```
Site_name | date& Time              | PowerOutput         
----------+-------------------------+------------------
ACT0001   | 2013-07-21 01:00:00.000 | 196.852984494331  
ACT0001   | 2013-07-21 02:00:00.000 | 196.852984494331   
xyz0001   | 2013-07-21 03:00:00.000 | 196.852984494331   
xyq0001   | 2013-07-21 04:00:00.000 | 196.958395639561 
xys0001   | 2013-07-21 05:00:00.000 | 196.958395639561
xyd0001   | 2013-07-21 06:00:00.000 | 197.20098185022 
xye0001   | 2013-07-21 07:00:00.000 | 197.20098185022 
xyg0001   | 2013-07-21 08:00:00.000 | 197.20098185022   
cfg0001   | 2013-07-21 09:00:00.000 | 197.412144323522 
acb0001   | 2013-07-21 10:00:00.000 | 197.412144323522
bdf0001   | 2013-07-21 11:00:00.000 | 197.412144323522
olk0001   | 2013-07-21 12:00:00.000 | 196.886233049016
```

Thank you

Comment: I can give you a hint: you can place your code into a while loop
`While Exists(select * from table where power = 0) then .... ` so in this case your proceudre will be recursive until you dont have zeros anymore!

Comment: You already asked same question and I replied answer.See this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40373762/how-to-calculate-the-average-value-and-update-it-in-place-of-zeros-using-ssis/40373911#40373911

Comment: `lead(pr_output,1) OVER (ORDER BY (select null))` ... shouldn't you order by the `date& Time` column? As it is written now, you will get arbitrary numbering on whatever order the database engine decides...

Comment: A good idea if you post (T-)SQL questions is to have sample data in the question to make it easy on people wanting to fiddle around with your query (or come up with a better solution). For instance here you will find an easy way to set up a sample data script: [How to post a T-SQL question on a public forum](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/). GL!

Comment: @ mansoor, it is not updating for consecutive zero's, i need top take the value before the zero and after the zero and then find the avergae value and update it in the table

Comment: "If this is true then it should remain as zero." Luckily, this is never true.

Comment: @Zeina: can you be elaborate please.

Answer (score 1):

If what you're trying to do is replace any zero values in `PowerOutput` with the most recent previous non-zero PowerOutput value only in cases where:

```
((Previous value-next value)/previous value)*100 <5
```

then I believe this does the trick:

```
SELECT  main.SiteName,
        main.[DateTime],
        CASE WHEN main.PowerOutput = 0 
            THEN CASE WHEN ((PreviousNonZero.PowerOutput - NextNonZero.PowerOutput) / PreviousNonZero.PowerOutput) * 100 < 5
                    THEN PreviousNonZero.PowerOutput
                    ELSE 0
                 END
            ELSE main.PowerOutput
        END AS PowerOutput
FROM [dbo].[My_table] main
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 PowerOutput 
    FROM [dbo].[My_table] prev 
    WHERE prev.[DateTime] < main.[DateTime]
    AND PowerOutput <> 0
    ORDER BY prev.[DateTime] DESC
) PreviousNonZero
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 PowerOutput 
    FROM [dbo].[My_table] future
    WHERE future.[DateTime] > main.[DateTime]
    AND PowerOutput <> 0
    ORDER BY future.[DateTime]
) NextNonZero
ORDER BY [DateTime]
```

I'm not 100% sure about whether this:

```
((Previous value-next value)/previous value)*100 <5
```

is really the logic you want to use though. It looks like you're trying to identify whether the value changes more or less than 5% from the previous non-zero value to the next one, but this will only work if the changes always occur in one direction, otherwise you get some negative values too (your sample dataset has values for this calculation ranging from about -0.23 to 0.27).

If what you want is to identify instances where the `PowerOutput` value is changing more than 5% (in either direction), I would alter the inner `CASE` statement in my query above from:

```
CASE WHEN ((PreviousNonZero.PowerOutput - NextNonZero.PowerOutput) / PreviousNonZero.PowerOutput) * 100 < 5
```

to:

```
CASE WHEN (ABS(PreviousNonZero.PowerOutput - NextNonZero.PowerOutput) / PreviousNonZero.PowerOutput) * 100 < 5
```

Answer (score 1):

I've done a different approach using an scalar function

```
                                CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[fnGetAvgPower] 
                (
                        @site_name varchar(50), @date_time datetime
                )
                RETURNS decimal(24,12) --Check the number of decimal you need here
                AS
                BEGIN
                    --
                    DECLARE @AvgPower decimal(24,12), @PrevValue decimal(24,12),@NextValue decimal(24,12), @Value decimal(24,12)--Check the number of decimal you need here


                    set @PrevValue = (Select Top 1 PowerOutput from Table_3 where Site_name = @site_name and datestamp < @date_time  and PowerOutput <> 0
                     order by datestamp desc)
                     set @NextValue = (Select Top 1 PowerOutput from Table_3 where Site_name = @site_name and datestamp > @date_time  and PowerOutput <> 0
                     order by datestamp asc)

                     set @Value = @PrevValue / @NextValue * 100

                     if(@Value is null) 

                     begin

                    set @Value= 0 
                    end
                    else
                    begin
                     set @Value = (Select case  when @Value > 5 then @PrevValue when @Value <= 5 then 0 end)

                     end
                    RETURN  @Value
            -- Call funtion
            update Table_3 set PowerOutput = dbo.fnGetAvgPower(Site_name,datestamp)
            where PowerOutput  = 0
```